# Activity Layout with Static and Dynamic Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm desiring to create this type of layout....

One static fragment created in xml on the left side

One static fragment created in xml on the bottom as a footer

One static fragment created in xml on the top as a header

and finally

One container for different dynamic fragments created @ runtime based on different broadcast from outside to the activity.

here's a visual....

[image: fragment_layout]

How can i structure this activity's layout in xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` to place top and bottom fragments, then in between add a horizontal `LinearLayout` containing List fragment and last dynamic fragment. The dimensions of the fragments can be put in `dimens` file, I have hardcoded `48` dp in xml; also the list area takes 20% of the width, while the content area takes the rest. Here's something to get you started with:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/top_fragment"
        android:name="com.adip.sampler.fragments.TopFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment"
        android:name="com.adip.sampler.fragments.BottomFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_fragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_fragment"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
            name="com.adip.sampler.fragments.ListFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_area"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

or if you want to have only viewgroups and no `fragment` tags you could have this layout (You can use any `ViewGroup` instead of `FrameLayout`, I am using it for efficiency reasons):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_fragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_fragment"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_area"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what if i wanted to do the same thing but dynamically across the board no fragments in xml...

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean with `dynamically across the board no fragments in xml` ?

Comment: Then instead of having the `fragment` tag you could have some view group there instead. Do you want me to edit the sample?

Comment: Edited, does it makes sense? Also, remember to upvote if you feel an answer is useful.